# NIntegrate evaluating symbolically instead of numerically

Tags: numerical-integration

I have defined a function $\phi(x,p_z)$ as the integral of another function via `NIntegrate`:

$$\phi(x,p_z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\text{int,1}}(x,p_z;k_p)\,dk_p$$

My function is supposed to evaluate numerically, but instead it's evaluating symbolically, which naturally means I have made a mistake somewhere. I have made sure to include `?NumericQ` in the arguments of the integrand definition, and have cleared all previous function definitions. Every minimal working example I try to construct ends up evaluating numerically like it's supposed to.

What's going on here? Is there something wrong going on with my function names?

---

```
ClearAll[M02, c, RZeros, kplus, kminus, kbplus, kbminus];
M02 = 0.1;
c = 1.2;
RZeros = y /. NSolve[y (1 - c y)^2 == M02, y, Reals];

kplus[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := -x*pz + Sqrt[RZeros[[i]] + kp + (x*pz)^2];
kminus[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := -x*pz - 
   Sqrt[RZeros[[i]] + kp + (x*pz)^2];
kbplus[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := (1. - x)*pz + 
   Sqrt[RZeros[[i]] + kp + ((1. - x)*pz)^2];
kbminus[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := (1. - x)*pz - 
   Sqrt[RZeros[[i]] + kp + ((1. - x)*pz)^2];

ClearAll[ybar1, BranchModifier1, N11, N12, D11, D12, D13, fint1];

ybar1[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := RZeros[[i]] - 2.*pz*kplus[x, pz, kp, i];
BranchModifier1 = {-1, -1, I};
N11[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := 
  BranchModifier1[[i]]*
   Sqrt[Abs[(1. - c*RZeros[[i]])*(1. - c*ybar1[x, pz, kp, i])]];
N12[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := 
  1. - c*((1. - x)*ybar1[x, pz, kp, i] + x*RZeros[[i]]);
D11[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := 
  Product[If[j != i, kplus[x, pz, kp, i] - kplus[x, pz, kp, j], 
    1.], {j, 1, Length[RZeros]}];
D12[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := 
  Product[kplus[x, pz, kp, i] - kminus[x, pz, kp, j], {j, 1, 
    Length[RZeros]}];
D13[x_, pz_, kp_, i_] := 
  ybar1[x, pz, kp, i]*(1. - c*ybar1[x, pz, kp, i])^2 - M02;
fint1[x_?NumericQ, pz_?NumericQ, kp_?NumericQ] := 
  Sum[(N11[x, pz, kp, i] N12[x, pz, kp, i])/(
   D11[x, pz, kp, i] D12[x, pz, kp, i] D13[x, pz, kp, i]), {i, 1, 
    Length[RZeros]}];

ClearAll[phi];

phi[x_, pz_] := 
  NIntegrate[fint1[x, pz, kp], {kp, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 40];

phi[0.6, 5]  (* should evaluate numerically! *)
NIntegrate[fint1[0.60000000000000000000, 5, kp], {kp, 0, \[Infinity]},
  MaxRecursion -> 40]
```

---

### [Edit: Partially Solved]

I just solved my problem, but don't understand why what I did solved my problem.

My integral was to be defined over the range $(-\infty,+\infty)$, but I accidentally defined it in MMA as being over $(0,+\infty)$. Changing this allowed my integral to be evaluated numerically.

Similarly, changing the bounds of integration to $(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are finite numbers, also allows my integral to be evaluated numerically.

Why is it that $(0,+\infty)$ does not evaluate numerically?

---

### [Edit 2: Take Back my Previous "Solution"]

I take back the supposed "solution" in my previous edit. The integral is supposed to be from $0$ to $+\infty$ only.

Comment: `BranchModifier` is not defined. You probably meant to use `BranchModifier1`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Ah, woops, I had actually defined `BranchModifier` identically in another notebook so fixing that doesn't change anything. See my most recent edit (bottom)

Answer (score 5):

> Why is it that (0,+∞) does not evaluate numerically?

Let us redefine `phi` to take options as:

```
ClearAll[phi];
phi[x_, pz_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  NIntegrate[fint1[x, pz, kp], {kp, 0, Infinity}, opts, MaxRecursion -> 40];
```

Calling `phi` with no options (as in the question) produces "NIntegrate::inumri":

```
phi[0.6, 5]  (*should evaluate numerically!*)
```

> During evaluation of In[52]:= NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand fint1[0.6,5,kp] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,3.67005*10^28}}.

```
(* NIntegrate[fint1[0.6, 5, kp], {kp, 0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 40] *)
```

Since the integral is calculated to infinity this message prompts that the [singularity handler](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792) is responsible. So, we can do a few things like:

- compute the integral without singularity handling and with smaller precision goal, or
- use a different singularity handler.

Here are some example calls:

```
phi[0.6, 5, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 4]

(* 0.200486 - 0.0614598 I *)

phi[0.6, 5, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
   "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}, PrecisionGoal -> 7]

(* 0.200478 - 0.0614822 I *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is really odd though because (a) the integrand is very well behaved for $k_p>0$ and (b) the answer in the end is finite. Would you have any guesses for why MMA isn't automatically handling whatever errors it's having with the integral? I ask this because your first example call seems to not really be changing much, and yet it does.

Comment: Well it can be shown following the code for the IMT variable transformation in [the reference documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792) I linked in my answer that the IMT transformations together with the [0,1) -> [0,Infinity] transformation produce infinite values for the integrant. In the code I suggested I just prevented the application of IMT.