# NIntegrate::zeroregion error

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

While integrating the following function,

```
me = 511000/29979200(*eV*);
re = 2.81794*10^-13(*cm*);
h = 4.135667516 * 10^-15;(*eV*)
c = 29979200;(*cm/s*)

Zg = 79;
Ag = 196.96655;
\[Rho] = 19.320(*g/\[Mu]m^3*);

\[Xi][\[Nu]_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := (100 me c^2 h \[Nu])/(
 T (T - h \[Nu] ) Zg^(1/3));(*Per Bremmstrahlung*)
\[Phi]1[T_?NumericQ, \[Nu]_?NumericQ] := 
 20.863 - 2 Log[1 + (0.55846 \[Xi][T, \[Nu]])^2] - 
  4 (1 - 0.6 Exp[-0.9 \[Xi][T, \[Nu]]] - 
     0.4 Exp[-105 \[Xi][T, \[Nu]]]);(*Per Bremmstrahlung*)
\[Phi]2[T_?NumericQ, \[Nu]_?NumericQ] := \[Phi]1[T, \[Nu]] - 
  2/3 1/(1 + 6.5 \[Xi][T, \[Nu]] + 
    6 \[Xi][T, \[Nu]]^2);(*Per Bremmstrahlung*)
f[Z_?NumericQ ] := (Z/137)^2 (1/(1 - (Z/137)^2) + 0.20206 - 
    0.0369 (Z/137)^2 + 0.0083 (Z/137)^4 - 
    0.002 (Z/137)^6);(*Per Bremmstrahlung*)

dEdx2[T_?NumericQ] := 
  6.022*10^23*\[Rho]/
   Ag NIntegrate[(4 Zg^2 re/
        137 1/\[Nu] (1 + (T/(T - h \[Nu]))^2) (\[Phi]1[T, \[Nu]]/4 - 
          1/3 Log[Zg] - f[Zg]) - 
       2/3 T/(T - 
         h \[Nu]) (\[Phi]2[T, \[Nu]] - 1/3 Log@Zg - f[Zg])), {\[Nu], 
      0, T/h}];

ParallelTable[{j, dEdx2[j]}, {j, 10000, 2*10^6, 10000}]
```

I get a very long series of errors, the first of which is

> NIntegrate::zeroregion Integration region {{2.41799*10^18,2.41798934786516787199999999993411568411875634969888072969436258221*10^18}} cannot be further subdivided at the specified working precision. NIntegrate assumes zero integral there and on any further indivisible regions.

What does it mean, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: You have constants that differ by dozens of orders of magnitude; numerical results will be catastrophically bad. Please, work in natural units, where all parameters are of order one.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I understand your point, but if you look at integral, all of the constant except for `h` are multiplicative.

Comment: So what? If most constants can be factored out, do so manually. The error message is telling you explicitly that the integral is numerically unstable. The very first step is to make it stable by working in natural units. Being a phd student in, I presume, physics/chemistry/engineering, you should know better by now: always use natural units, and especially when doing numerics!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtaining a zero length integration region means that most likely the singularity handler is not aggressive enough.

So, one way to deal with your problem is to try to change the singularity handler and/or the precision goal. Here is [an answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176639/34008) doing that for [a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176638/34008).

Further, you can rationalize all the numerical entities and use higher precision. (Not done here.)

First let us redefine `dEdx2`:

```
ClearAll[dEdx2]
Options[dEdx2] = Options[NIntegrate];
dEdx2[T_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  6.022*10^23*\[Rho]/
    Ag NIntegrate[(4 Zg^2 re/
        137 1/\[Nu] (1 + (T/(T - h \[Nu]))^2) (\[Phi]1[T, \[Nu]]/4 - 
         1/3 Log[Zg] - f[Zg]) - 
      2/3 T/(T - h \[Nu]) (\[Phi]2[T, \[Nu]] - 1/3 Log@Zg - 
         f[Zg])), {\[Nu], 0, T/h}, opts];
```

This takes less than 40s on my laptop (without any messages):

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res3 = 
   Table[
     {j, 
      dEdx2[j, 
       Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}, 
       MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 3]}, 
     {j, 10000, 2*10^6, 10000}];
 ]
Short[res3]

(* {37.456, Null} *)

(* {{10000, -6.33661*10^43}, {20000, -1.26732*10^44}, {30000, \
-1.92223*10^44}, {40000, -2.53464*10^44}, {50000, -3.18431*10^44}, \
{60000, -3.84447*10^44} ... } *)
```

The computation above with `PrecisionGoal->4` takes ~15 times longer; the results are assigned to `res4`. Here are the relative errors:

```
Through[{Min, Max, Mean, Median}[
  Abs[(res4[[All, 2]] - res3[[All, 2]])/res4[[All, 2]]]]]

(* {0., 0.0134694, 0.00151681, 0.000671349} *)
```

Comment: What is `res4` ?

Comment: What  result you  assigned?